# При получении данных из DataFrame получаю массив в массиве, нужно получить один массив

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame со следующими данными:

[image: DataFrame]

При получении scores по индексу корректно получаю массив:
result_df['scores'][0]

[image: scores]

Но если хочу получить значения `scores` по конкретному `image_id`, то получаю массив в массиве:
sample_id = '9b783b776'

scores =result_df[result_df['image_id'] == sample_id]['scores'].values
#scores = scores.astype(np.float32)
scores

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как при поиске по конкретному `image_id`, получить массив?

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7060).

Comment: Неужели вставить данные в виде текста тяжелее, чем влепить в вопрос скриншоты? Представьте, вам ответы в виде фотографий запостят?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scores, = result_df[resu1t_df['image_id'] == sample_id]['scores'].values
```

(заметите запятую на левой стороне).

---

*Объяснение:*

Результатом выражения

```
result_df[resu1t_df['image_id'] == sample_id]
```

есть **всегда** датафрейм, хотя в вашем случае вероятно 1-строковый.

Когда вы из него выберете 1 столбец применением `['scores']`:

```
result_df[resu1t_df['image_id'] == sample_id]['scores']
```

вы получите **серию**, хотя в вашем случае только 1-элементную.

Но и когда затем примените атрибут `.values`:

```
result_df[resu1t_df['image_id'] == sample_id]['scores'].values
```

вы получите **поле (numpy array)**, хотя в вашем случае опять только 1-элементное.

Но тот 1 элемент результатного поля является **тоже полем**, значит, получите 1-элементное поле, из которого нужно выбрать единый элемент — внутренние поле — например так:

```
scores, = result_df[resu1t_df['image_id'] == sample_id]['scores'].values
```

(Запятая на левой стороне означает 1-элеменую кортеж.)

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас значения в столбце `image_id` уникальные, то можете просто взять `[0]` от своего выражения, да и всё:

```
scores = [...] .values[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать индекс и выбирать данные через .at

```
result_df.set_index('image_id').at[sample_id, 'scores']
```

Тут уж смотрите на размер датафрейма и производительность

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

Воспроизводимый пример данных (DataFrame):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  "id": [1,2,3],
  "scores": [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
})
```

---

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
   id     scores
0   1  [1, 2, 3]
1   2  [4, 5, 6]
2   3  [7, 8, 9]
```

Будем искать значения `scores` для `id == 2`.

**Вариант 1:** - используем [`df.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
res = df.loc[df["id"] == 2, "scores"].to_numpy()[0]
```

**Вариант 2:** - используем [`df.at[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) и [`Series.idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
res = df.at[(df["id"] == 2).idxmax(), "scores"]
```

результат:

```
In [19]: res
Out[19]: [4, 5, 6]
```